# Function "timeout" doesn't exist in this Service

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I have the following function definition within my serverless.yml file (AWS)

```
taskUpload:
    timeout: 900
    handler: build/schedules/something/task.task
    package:
      include:
        - "build/schedules/something/task.js"
        - "env.json"
    events:
      - schedule:
```

Within my deploy i'm doing `sls deploy function -f taskUpload` i get the following error message and i cant figure out what i've done wrong. If i run `sls deploy` i do not get the error message.

```
Serverless Error --------------------------------------- 
Function "timeout" doesn't exist in this Service
```

The docs say i can have timeout, so i guess something else is wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please post the entire `serverless.yml` file?

Answer (score 0):

you may have already found the solution but just in case other wayward developers (like myself) stumble upon this, it is because `taskUpload` is the function. `timeout` is just a param of that function.